# How to set a click to expand on a table view cell in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am coding an app for iOS and have a custom cell class as follows:

```
import UIKit

class cell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var NameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var DescriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CreatorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var TypeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var LocationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var noneFoundLabel: UILabel!
}
```

This custom cell is referred to in the tableview as follows:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell
    //Do the stuff
}
```

The cell is iterated by calling the count of an array and works fine. Is there anyway such that the cell size is a bit smaller on the display so it only displays the name and description, and once clicked on will expand to show the user the rest of the info. And then once clicked off, it will collapse again?

Answer (score 1):

Quite possible. You need to keep track of which cells are expanded. Add this information to the data used by your data source.

Implement the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function. Based on whether the given `indexPath` is expanded or not, return the appropriate height.

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, configure the cell based on whether it is expanded or not.

Implement the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function. Toggle the state of the expansion for the given `indexPath` and reload the row at that index path.